# How to set excel cell background color with System color in NPOI

Tags: c#, .net, npoi, hssf

I have an object of class `Foo` with attribute `StatusColor` being used in multiple locations.
Now, I have to generate an Excel file using NPOI in which the column `Status Color` should have the same color as the object.

I do not know how to set `System.Drawing.Color` as CellStyle color, please help.

I would like something like:

```
class Foo{
    //Properties..
    System.Drawing.Color StatusColor {get;set;}
}

...

//Creating Status Style
var statusStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
statusStyle.FillForegroundColor = fooObject.StatusColor; //Of course, it won't work.
//Is there way to convert from System.Color to HSSFColor?
statusStyle.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;

...

//Set Style
excelCell.CellStyle = style;
```

**In-Short:** 
How can I convert `System.Drawing.Color` into `HSSFColor` color index?

**I tried:**
I have written a function to convert (from `Color` to `HSSFColor` index), but not sure how many `if-else` have to be written.

```
public static short ToHSSFColorIndex(Color color)
{
    if (Color.Green.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.Green.Index;
    else if (Color.Green.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.LightGreen.Index;
    else if (Color.Red.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.Red.Index;
    else if (Color.DarkRed.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.DarkRed.Index;
    else if (Color.Gray.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.Grey50Percent.Index;
    else if (Color.Blue.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.Blue.Index;
    else if (Color.Yellow.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.Yellow.Index;
    else if (Color.YellowGreen.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.LightYellow.Index;
    else if (Color.White.ToArgb().Equals(color.ToArgb()))
        return HSSFColor.White.Index;
    else
        return HSSFColor.COLOR_NORMAL;
}
```

Comment: maybe this will help - https://github.com/tonyqus/npoi/blob/master/examples/hssf/FillBackgroundInXls/Program.cs

Comment: OP and up-voter perhaps need a refresher of [ask]

Comment: Thanks @piedpiper, but I could not find if System.Color being used in the code. Can you please give line number you want me to refer to?

Comment: What is `SystemColor`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @jean-francois-t, Sorry, I meant System.Drawing.Color.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
var color = new XSSFColor(fooObject.StatusColor);
statusStyle.FillForegroundColor = color.Indexed;
```